# Issue with updated MariaDB using older version

Tags: wordpress, mariadb

### Environment

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Nginx 1.13.12
- PHP-FPM 7.2
- MariaDB  (was 10.1.31, updated to 10.2.15)

### Issue

I updated MariaDB from 10.1 to 10.2.
The server shows that 10.2.15 (with MySQL 5.7.22) is running on the server. I've tested that with `mysql -u root -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";'`, and also with `service mysql status`. Both show the above is true.

In Wordpress it continues to show that the database system version is 10.1.31. That information comes up in the various Server Information plug-ins that are available (the one I mostly use is `WP SERVER STATS`, and also shows up in the WooCommerce status page, where it has a DB version warning, `MySQL Version: 5.5.5 - We recommend a minimum MySQL version of 5.6`.

Thinking something was perhaps hanging over after the update, I restarted the server, and this didn't resolve it.

### Question

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on Sol's answer...

The issue is something Wordpress developers know about. It caused by servers with MariaDB not providing the right response to the Wordpress `is_mysql` function. It should be returning `false`, but it is not.

Wordpress dev classes it as a `wontfix` issue, as [it's not considered critical](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/20227#issuecomment-392002729), and is something they say the host needs to resolve with a suitable "dropin" for MariaDB. I have no idea what a MariaDB "dropin" is, and after a few minutes of searching online to find out, I came up empty handed.

> It seems database dropins should be setting is_mysql 
>   https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/34655

**As it's of no consequence (other than the erroneous error message), it's safe to just leave this issue as it is, and move on.**

Answer (score 1):

this appears to be an issue with woocommerce:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/11117